# How to export the list of images from chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome

I am currently optimizing my application.got to know that there where may image requests.i am able to see the image requests using chrome Dev tools,but is there a way to export all the image files names into a file ?

[image]

Comment: you can get the source of all the `img` tag, using jquery or native browser api, but that will get you the full path... is that what you are looking for? tell me and i'll post a snippet as an answer.

Comment: Yes @BasselShmali that is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this in your browser console, and you should get an array of all your images sources:

```
var arrOfImgsSources = [];
$.each($("img"), function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    arrOfImgsSources.push(imgsrc);
});
console.log(arrOfImgsSources);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bassel it helps

Answer (score 1):

For pages without jQuery - or if you don't want to import it by yourself - the solution could be like this:

```
const arrOfImgsSources = [];
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    const imgsrc = document.images[i].src;
    arrOfImgsSources.push(imgsrc);
};
console.log(arrOfImgsSources);
```

You can test it right on this page:

1. open developer tools
2. copy and past code above
3. press enter
4. get URLs of images in console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).